# IFogSim: Link between the GUI and the code

Tags: java, cloudsim

Are there any links between the GUI and the code in IFogSim toolkit?

What I found is that code does not work with the typology made by GUI. Instead, the typology built in the code is the one used in the program. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my idea, there is no link between topology made by GUI to remaining code in ifogsim.
Code we write in the program creates the topology.